# Thread based function in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, multithreading

how to create a function in Node.js such that each time it is called it executes in a separate thread.

Comment: Depends on the case. Use child_process or check Node worker threads.

Comment: I want on any implementation example.

Comment: Check Node documentation, it already contains examples. Asking for examples is off-topic on SO. Consider re-asking the question once you will have specific piece of code you have problems with.

Comment: Example: https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_threads

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt I did consider that but the whole file gets executed I just want one function to get executed per thread.